# how can I remove the sidebar from my wp homepage

Tags: wordpress

What's the best practice when it comes to removing the sidebar on the wordpress homepage? I'm using wp Version 3.2.1 and Skeleton Child Theme 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your home page as one page instead of any or all posts.

for this you have to add your home page as a page from admin Settings->Reading
and for the Front page display select A static page form from the given radio buttons and set your preferred page there as your home page.

this can be helpful to you if you don't want to display your sidebar only for home page and that page is not a post page.

for more help see this,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: SOLVED: after following your steps I also set the template on my "Edit Page" screen to "Designer Page - No Sidebar or Page Title"